# PL/SQL for parsing EDI (X12, NCPDP, HL7)

Tags: plsql, edi, hl7, x12

I have some EDI messages (X12, HL7, etc ...) stored in an Oracle database.  I sometimes want to pull out individual fields (e.g. ISA-03).  Currently, I have some really ugly sql.  I'd like to create a PL/SQL package to make it easier and was wondering if anybody had already done this.

I imagine something like:

select
   edi.x12.extract_field( clob_column, 'ISA', 4)
from
   edi_table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I never stored the HL7 message as is in a database it should be possible.

The idea of HL7 (and XML) is that it's a common format for systems to use to transfer information.  It was never designed as a "storable" item.  Usually, I would pull the data out of the warehouse format into a particular HL7 message and send it to the MQHub/eGate for transmitting.  On the return do the opposite extract the fields I'm warehousing and save those.  I.E. HL7 should not be stored so I don't have one.

Enough of the lecture. :)

I would suggest a function/procedure per segment and split the message into a temp table.

[example of split in oracle](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5259821.html)